# Take a single String of a RecyclerView, OnClick and Pass this string to a Google Maps Search

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing a google Maps Activity in my app and i'd like to give to this maps Activity a search via address. These addresses are stored in a Firestore RecyclerView and i'd like to let map show the address when the user click on one of the Firestore RecyclerView Rows...

> Here's the Holder

```
 public class RecyclerViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mnomeEsercente, mindirizzoEsercente;

    public RecyclerViewHolder1(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mnomeEsercente = itemView.findViewById(R.id.roWnomeEsercente);
        mindirizzoEsercente = itemView.findViewById(R.id.roWindirizzoEsercente);
    }
}
```

> Here's the adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder1> {

    Esercenti esercenti;
    ArrayList<User1> user1ArrayList;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter1(Esercenti esercenti, ArrayList<User1> user1ArrayList) {
        this.esercenti = esercenti;
        this.user1ArrayList = user1ArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder1 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(esercenti.getBaseContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_rowesercenti, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder1(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder1 holder, int position) {
        holder.mnomeEsercente.setText(user1ArrayList.get(position).getNomeEsercente());
        holder.mindirizzoEsercente.setText(user1ArrayList.get(position).getIndirizzoEsercente());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return user1ArrayList.size();
    }
}
```

> And there's the Activity

```
public class Esercenti extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    FirebaseFirestore db1;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerViewEsercenti;
    ArrayList<User1> user1ArrayList;
    GoogleMap map;
    RecyclerViewAdapter1 adapter1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_esercenti);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        user1ArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        setUpRecyclerView();
        setUpFirebase();
        loadDataFromFirebase();
    }

    private void loadDataFromFirebase() {

        if (user1ArrayList.size() > 0)
            user1ArrayList.clear();

        db1.collection("esercenti").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                            User1 user1 = new User1(querySnapshot.getString("nomeEsercente"), querySnapshot.getString("indirizzoEsercente"));

                            user1ArrayList.add(user1);
                        }
                        adapter1 = new RecyclerViewAdapter1(Esercenti.this, user1ArrayList);
                        mRecyclerViewEsercenti.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Esercenti.this, "Problema di caricamento,controlla la tua connessione!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setUpFirebase() {
        db1 = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerViewEsercenti = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewEsercenti);
        mRecyclerViewEsercenti.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerViewEsercenti.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        map = googleMap;
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        LatLng base = new LatLng(0, 0);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(base).title("Sede AirBc"));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(base));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    }
}
```

How to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by following some steps. I have mentioned below.

1. Register click event on RecyclerView item.
2. Retrieve Model for that position.
3. Set marker for that location on your map. (If you have only address in your model then retrieve lat/long for that address)

You have to follow the same procedure on every RecyclerView item click event.

Let me know if you need something more from me.

Hope this help :)